# Не переведена плашка "Highly active question. You have enough reputation to answer or unprotect this question."

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, защищённые-вопросы

Не переведена плашка для защищенных вопросов, когда репутации хватает для снятия защиты или ответа:

[image: У вас достаточно репутации]

Пример вопроса с такой плашкой: [no module named 'codecs' при запуске cx_Freeze-скомпилированной программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617151/no-module-named-codecs-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-cx-freeze-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B)

Comment: Плашка для случая, когда репутации не хватает для ответа или пользователь незалогинен переведена. Промежуточный случай проверить не могу.

Comment: Я вижу как на скриншоте.

Comment: Появился перевод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Временно добавил перевод, чтоб хоть какой-то был:

> **Вопрос с повышенной активностью**. У вас достаточно репутации, чтобы ответить или снять защиту с этого вопроса.

Если есть идеи получше, предлагайте в ответах.